# Can we say anything about $fg*h$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, convolution, harmonic-analysis

Can we say anything about $fg*h$, for example... is it true that
$$(fg)*h=f(g*h)?$$
seems that not, because not necessaryly
$$f(x)\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x-y)h(y)dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (fg)(x-y)h(y)dy.$$
But can we anything of the type hölder (for example)
$$\|f*(gh)\|_1\leq \|f*g\|_p\|h\|_q$$
such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$? Thanks!

Comment: Start by telling us what $f,g,h$ are, then what $*$ means. We can’t read your mind.

Comment: @Thomas * is convoluction, f, g and h are functions ( tempered distribuctions for example). I think that its clear in view of the context of the question...

Comment: What's clear to you might not be clear at all to others:) when posting on MSE, try to state your problem clearly - this helps you get a better grasp of the problem too!

Comment: @JustDroppedln really, I Will try be better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this qualifies as an answer, but what you can say is that
$$\|(fg)*h\|_1\leq\min\{\|f\|_\infty\cdot\|g*h\|_1,\|g\|_\infty\cdot\|f*h\|_1\} $$

because $$\|(fg)*h\|_1=\int|f(x-y)g(x-y)h(y)|dy\leq\|f\|_\infty\int|g(x-y)h(y)|dy=\|f\|_\infty\|g*h\|_1 $$
and likewise one shows that $\|(fg)*h\|_1\leq\|g\|_\infty\|f*h\|_1$.

Also, the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm is submultiplicative with respect to convolution, so you can also deduce that $\|(fg)*h\|_1\leq\|fg\|_1\cdot\|h\|_1$ and then use Holder's inequality to deduce that $\|(fg)*h\|_1\leq\|f\|_p\|g\|_q\|h\|_1$ for all $p,q$ with $1/p+1/q=1$.

Comment: Can we put f*g in the same Norm?

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva I don't think $f*g$ has anything to do with the question.